# View PDF from link without saving/downloading in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, pdf, url, android-webview

I actually have some **pdf files**(only for **paid** users) on my server and the goal is to let the user view the content of those files **without able to download/save** it.

Is there any way by which I can make this possible? Either with **WebView** or any **dependency**?
Please Help!!
**Kotlin** codes or helps will be much appreciated.
Thank You!!

Comment: As soon as the user can see that pdf document it is already downloaded i would say.

Comment: try this https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you follow this guide i think you can reach your achievement
https://blog.mindorks.com/how-to-open-a-pdf-file-in-android-programmatically

Comment: Thank you broo...It worked with some modifications.

Comment: happy to be usefull, happy coding